# Calling From WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am working on an app that runs on webview.
Their is a link that automatically dials a number, but if I add it to my WebView and I click the link, it quits my application.

```
 myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.calleridfaker.com");
 myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
{


   setTitle("Loading ..... This app uses Internet connection");
   // setProgress(progress * 100);
    setProgress(progress);




    if(progress == 100)
        setTitle(R.string.app_name);


    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementById('id_my_phoneno').value ='"+phoneNumber+"'};"); 
      myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementById('id_email').value ='"+possibleEmail+"'};"); 
      myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementById('admob').style.display ='none'};"); 
      myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementById('download-apps').style.display ='none'};"); 
      myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementById('id_record').style.display ='none'};"); 
      myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: {document.getElementById('secondHeader').style.display ='none'};"); 


     myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
             "document.getElementsByTagName('small')[0].style.display = 'none'; " +
             "})()");
     myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
             "document.getElementsByTagName('img')[2].style.display = 'none'; " +
             "})()");
     myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
             "document.getElementsByTagName('div')[20].style.display = 'none'; " +
             "})()");
     myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
             "document.getElementsByTagName('div')[15].style.display = 'none'; " +
             "})()");

   }
 });

}}
```

There is a link, which is causing, that when I click it in WebView,  the application closes.

Comment: you must post the concerned code so that we can tell where your going wrong.